# Python Type Extension w/ Numpy Array Reference Count Behavior

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reference-counting, python-c-extension

I am writing a C extension for a new python Type. One of the attributes for this new type will be a Numpy array that comes from external data passed into the C extension. I define the attribute array like this:

```
array = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(numDims,shape,NPY_DOUBLE,[DATA POINTER])
```

with [DATA POINTER] being the location of the external data in memory.

I then use this command to set the array attribute's "base" to the type object that contains the attribute:

```
PyArray_SetBaseObject((PyArrayObject*)array,(PyObject*)[PY_TYPE OBJECT])
```

Now, to the best of my understanding, when I import my module, the "type" of `object.array` is `numpy.ndarray`.

When I take a normal ndarray and preform the following commands, I see the subsequent behavoir:

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>import sys
>>>base = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>>sys.getrefcount(base)
2
>>>newArr = base
>>>sys.getrefcount(base)
3
>>>del newArr
>>>sys.getrefcount(base)
2
```

I want my array attribute to increment and decrement  its base's reference count just like `newArr` incremented and then decremented `base`'s reference count. However, my module behaves like this:

```
>>>from myModule import myObj
>>>import sys
>>>base = myObj()
>>>sys.getrefcount(base)
2
>>>newArr = base.array
>>>sys.getrefcount(base)
2
>>>del newArr
>>>sys.getrefcount(base)
2
```

Does anyone know how I can get use of my `array` attribute to alter the reference count of my base type object? My original thought was to use this numpy ndarray behavior, but I am open to comments and suggestions!

Comment: If `base.array` already exists before you access it, accessing `base.array` shouldn't create a new reference to `base`. Why would it?

Comment: Note that, as [explicitly documented](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_SetBaseObject), `PyArray_SetBaseObject` **steals** a reference.

Comment: I guess I am slightly confused; `newArray = base.array` creates a new reference to `base.array` yes? I then want to create a new reference to `base` because that is the object that is storing the information contained in `base.array`. Is a stolen reference incapable of accomplishing this?

Comment: Yeah, but you're not checking the refcount of `base.array`. You're checking the refcount of `base`.

Comment: Sorry, still figuring out stack overflow and posted my comment before it was finished

Comment: A reference to `base.array` is fundamentally not a reference to `base`. What you're trying to accomplish is based on a misunderstanding of Python's reference counting system. (As for the stolen reference thing, I mentioned that because you seem to be forgetting to `Py_INCREF` the base object before `PyArray_SetBaseObject`, so you're going to cause memory corruption. This error is in the creation of `base.array` and has nothing to do with what happens to `base`'s refcount when you *access* `base.array`.)

Comment: Consider this behavior:

`>>>a = np.array([1,2,3])

>>>sys.getrefcount(a)

2

>>>b = a

>>>c = b

>>>sys.getrefcount(a)

4`

From my understanding of this code, `c=b` increases the reference count of `a` because `a` is the "base" of `b`. I want the "base" of `base.array` to be `base` so that when I call `newArr = base.array`, a reference to `base` is created. It seems like this should work...

Comment: "c=b increases the reference count of a because a is the "base" of b" - wrong. `a` is not the base of `b`. `a` and `b` are both references to the same exact array, and `c=b` makes a new reference to that array.

Comment: Also sorry about the poor code description, apparently carriage returns don't work in the comments...

Comment: What is the purpose of treating reference count of "base" the same as "base.array"?

Comment: `base` is going to be a data type with multiple different attributes, many of which will be arrays with pointers back to a single memory block for their entries. We want to increment the type object each time one of the arrays is called and decrement it when they're deleted, so that we know when it is safe to deallocate that single memory block they all point back to.